# Access, After Insert and the missing ID

Tags: ms-access

I'm have to create an access web database and running into a frustrating problem when inserting a record into a table.

I'm trying to use the *After Insert* macro to set a problem number field, thusly:

```
Edit Record
SetField
Name: [Problem Number]
Value =: [ID] (There is no more logic here but even this simplest case fails)
```

The problem is that ID doesn't have a value so Problem number ends up blank.

This logic works on an *After Update* which makes sense as it has an ID at that point.

Is there anyway I achieve this without switching to VB code.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. You do not want to use the after update event to modify the current record since it would in theory cause the before update event and the after update event to fire AGAIN. This potentially would cause a circular loop.

And if you think about this it makes little sense RIGHT after you JUST saved the record all nice to the table then you edit the record again! In fact you find by design that the current record in context is read only in that after update event. So you cannot execute an edit record on the current record in context in the after update event and you get a "read only" error if you check the error log.

In the before change event, [id] is not available. However, you can most certainly pick up and use the [id] in the after update event.

However, if you are going to create a NEW record in another table, then the NEXT line outside of the create record block allows you to pick up the just created record with

```
[LastCreateRecordIdentity]
```

So the record write occurs on the next line outside of the create record block.

For example here is some code that creates a new record and note VERY careful the "indentation" of the code.

[image]

If fact if you click on the create record command in the above then the WHOLE create block of code will highlight. Note how the NEXT line of code is OUTSIDE of the blue code block and that is the code where we can use [LastCreateRecordIdentity].

The blue highlighted code is thus this:

[image]

So the NEXT line right outside of the create record is when you can pick up the new id. In the above I actually "return" the new id just created via the returnVars to the calling routine.

Comment: Very nice. I was getting a little frustrated with this so I moved onto another part of the project for a while. When I'm back in on Monday I'll have another look at this.