# MS Access After Insert Macro

Tags: ms-access

I've been automating a process at work.
I use an Access database (2010) and it's working real nice.

For my questions the relevant tables are: Inorder and Exceptions
Inorder: All the information in here goes in to an order, including a DeviceID and an exception column
Exceptions: All the exceptions are written here, we need that in the inorder table with a DeviceID, Date and an Exception (description)

When the Inorder table is filled, an update query runs updating every Inorder.Exception column with the relevant Exception (works perfect, no problems here).

What i need is the following:
When a user inserts a row in to the table Inorder the exceptions table needs to be checked and if there is an exception for the Date and the DeviceID in the Exceptions table the Inorder.Exception column must be filled.

What I've searched:
Using Datamacro's because triggers do not exist in Access 2010
[MS Access trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807%28v=office.14%29.aspx
[Access, After Insert and the missing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801744/access-after-insert-and-the-missing-id)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/video-create-a-data-macro-VA100305331.aspx
And several other Microsoft sites.

I've tried multiple setups but it doesn't give me the expected outcome.
 I cant figure out how to get the relevant data from the Exceptions table to the Inorder table.
I don't really get the GUI at all.... Could someone help me along?

Comment: Access 2010 most certanly has table triggers (try reading  your links closer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your `Before Change` event on your `Inorder` table. I'm kind of guessing about your table structure but give it a whirl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
<DataMacro Event="BeforeChange">
<Statements>
    <ConditionalBlock>
        <If>
            <Condition>DCount("ExceptionID","Exceptions","DeviceID =" &amp; [Inorder].[DeviceID] &amp; "Date =#" &amp; [Inorder].[Date] &amp; "#")&gt;0</Condition>
        <Statements><Action Name="SetField">
            <Argument Name="Field">Inorder.Exception</Argument>
            <Argument Name="Value">DLookUp("ExceptionID","Exceptions","DeviceID =" &amp; [Inorder].[DeviceID] &amp; "Date =#" &amp; [Inorder].[Date] &amp; "#")</Argument>
        </Action>
        </Statements>
        </If>
        </ConditionalBlock>
    </Statements>
</DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```