# Get data from another table in a ms Access data macro

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a tblCustomer and a tblContact, where the information ultimately comes from two different other programs. In order to get around complex ID issues and keep things easy for users, I'm trying to do the following:

If either the CompMyobID or Company (lookup which points to the Primary Key autonumber in tblCustomer) field of a tblContact record are updated, the data macro finds the corresponding tblCustomer record, and uses the Primary Key or the MyobID to update the non-updated field in tblContact.

To achieve that, I've created the following after-update macro - First an If to work out if one of those fields (and which one) has been updated, then an EditRecord, alias not set in order to edit the current record where I SetField the field with the other name to... and that's where I get stuck. I tried to just run some sql, but at the moment nothing actually happens when I update either field...

[image: data macro screengrab]

---

Edit:

Because, as Erik pointed out, this method locks me out of the current record, and opens me up to recursive issues, Here's another angle that's not yet working:

in a Before Change Data Macro, the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two main errors in that data macro:

1. The just updated record in an after update macro is read-only. This means calling *EditRecord* will fail. You can work around that by looking up the record you just updated, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853330/7296893), but this requires you
2. You can't just set the value equal to an SQL clause, and expect the database to execute that clause. Usually, you could lookup records using `DLookUp`, but data macro's use the `Look Up A Record In` blocks to look up records instead

The final macro should look something like this (only updating one):

```
If Updated("CompMyobID") Or Updated("Company") Then
    SetLocalVar
        NewID
        =[ID]
    SetLocalVar
        NewCompany
        =Company
    SetLocalVar
        NewCompMyobID
        =CompMyobID
    If Updated("CompMyobID")
        Look Up A Record In tblCustomer
        Where Condition     CompMyobID = NewCompMyobID
        Alias               T

            SetLocalVar
                LookupCompany
                =T.ID
        For Each Record In  tblContact
        Where Condition     ID = NewID
            EditRecord
                SetField
                    Company
                    LookupCompany
            End EditRecord
    End If
End If
```

A strong warning: This macro will recursively call itself the way you have designed it! If you update Company, the macro will edit CompMyobID, triggering the macro, then updating Company again, triggering it again, etc.

Access has protection against recursive macro's, so aside from the errors you're triggering, you will probably not notice the recursion, and it won't cause performance problems. I strongly recommend not relying on this protection, and not storing information that could be looked up, but instead using a relation to look up the appropriate company name.

---

In the end, after the comment discussion below, We used a *Before Change* data macro, which avoids the need to look up the changed record before altering it, and avoids the chance of the macro calling itself because a `Before Update` macro edits the current record before it gets updated, instead of updating it again after it gets updated. We changed the macro to check if the value was `Null` or a zero-length string because `Updated` is not available in a before update macro.

The final solution was equal to the last edit of the question, with the exception of using `Company & "" = ""` instead of `Company = ""` to account for Null values.

You can read more on Null vs zero-length string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32489815/7296893). The essence is that a zero-length string is just a string with 0 characters, but Null is a place where no value has been entered. Null behaves a bit oddly, returning Null when you compare it with anything. This means `Null = "A"` is Null, and gets treated as false, but `Null <> "A"` is also Null, and also gets treated as false.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable. I've shared the technique for looking up records from different tables, and using localvars to set your record equal to these looked-up records. Do you still need help?

Comment: Yeah... It's still not working. I think I've followed the relevant bits of your advice, and transferred it over, but I must have missed something...

Comment: Don't use strings in the where condition and string concatenation. This isn't VBA, it's a data macro, and the `WHERE` condition gets parsed as SQL directly. Also, try providing the error. Those get logged in the  table USysApplicationLog

Comment: I don't see such a table. I have in the past, but there currently isn't one, and I've done the things that should have triggered that macro a couple of times.

Do I need to set more variables to make the where condition work then? I've used strings in where conditions within macros before with some success... stuff like:

`="[Company] LIKE " & "'*" & [SearchInput] & "*'"`

Comment: Macro's and data macros are very different things. Macro's are more like VBA and get processed by the application, data macro's get processed by the database engine. You don't need to set any variables, you just need to remove those quotes. My example doesn't contain any quotes, except inside the `Updated` function.

Comment: wait, but how does it know which table's field I'm referencing then?

Comment: You use `SetLocalVar` to alias the fields, like in my example.

Comment: Ok, I've updated it according to these comments as far as I can see so far. I have to leave the office or my wife is going to kill me. Any further feedback you have on my latest update to the question would be hugely appreciated when I read it tomorrow morning.

Comment: The only further comment I have is that you're not checking for null values. I often use `If Company & "" = ""` to account for both null values and zero-length strings.

Comment: Amazing. That did it. One of these days I'm going to properly get my head around the difference between a null value and an empty string.
Thank you!
I've accepted your answer, but for the sake of the deeper value of this question, can I request that you put a secondary solution in that reflects the eventual solution that solved all the issues? Or tell me to add it to your answer and accept the edit - I'd feel strange doing it without asking first.

Comment: I've added some clarification on the final solution in the answer. You can add a screenshot (or the [AXL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487686/7296893)) in the answer, if you feel that's useful for future readers. If you do, refer to this comment in the edit description, to avoid the edit being rejected.